# Remotely start (trigger) an EC2 amazon windows server with an URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My server is stopped when idle (no more charge from aws), but I'm trying to figure out an easy way to send a command via the web to the AWS control **to start** my Windows EC2 server. I look everywhere and can't find anything easy to implement.

Comment: Setup API gateway with lambda proxy integration. The lambda will start the instance.

Comment: Hello @Marcin, thank you for you answer. Any example of API Gateway + Lambda proxy integration I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments. [API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) with lambda proxy integration. The lambda will start the instance. A good tutorial on the lambda and api gateway setup is here:

- [Build an API Gateway API with Lambda Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)

Comment: I will presume that someone with experience will do that in less than 30 minutes. Anyone to recommand? It will take many hours for me if not days... 

Comment: I think there are other website more suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: @JohnM No problem. If the answer was useful, accepting it would be appreciated.

Comment: I created my first Pet Store :)